# How to concise following jquery code snippet

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have the following jQuery code and it works fine but it loads very slowly. i am not a pro in jQuery so can anyone help me make following code snippet more concise? I will appreciate this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // colorpicker field
    jQuery('.twb_btn_color, .twb_spam_clr, .twb_btn_txt_color, .twb_bg_color, .twb_main_title_color, .twb_sub_title_color')
        .each(function(){
            var $this = jQuery(this),
                id = $this.attr('rel');
            $this.farbtastic('#' + id).hide();
            jQuery('.twb, .twb-title').click(function() {
                jQuery('.twb_btn_color').fadeIn('medium').siblings("div").hide();
            });
            jQuery('.twb-spam, .twb-spam-title').click(function() {
                jQuery('.twb_spam_clr').fadeIn('medium').siblings("div").hide();
            });
            jQuery('.twb-btn-txt-color, .twb-btn-txt-color-title').click(function() {
                jQuery('.twb_btn_txt_color').fadeIn('medium').siblings("div").hide();
            });
            jQuery('.twb-bg-color, .twb-bg-color-title').click(function() {
                jQuery('.twb_bg_color').fadeIn('medium').siblings("div").hide();
            });
            jQuery('.twb-main-title-color, .twb-main-title-color').click(function() {
                    jQuery('.twb_main_title_color').fadeIn('medium').siblings("div").hide();
            });
            jQuery('.twb-sub-title-color, .twb-sub-title-color').click(function() {
                jQuery('.twb_sub_title_color').fadeIn('medium').siblings("div").hide();
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't need to bind event handler in each block. Move them to _document ready_ handler

Comment: Can you please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The typical way of handling this is to give all the elements that you want to perform the same action on **the same class name**.

Also, so that you don't have to bind the event to each of them, you can delegate the event on a common parent, in this case we'll use `body`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.common-class-name', function () {
   $(this).fadeIn('medium').siblings("div").hide();
});
```

This requires that you give all the elements the same class name. You can then reference the one that has been clicked with `$(this)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, It did not solve my issue. Because on click it should triggers a function in a separete div. Not in the same div so $(this) will not work here.

HTML code structure is like following:

    `<input class="common_class-name" />
    <div class="div that loads when clicked on common class name"></div>`

Comment: @absikandar If they are always relative then you might be able to use something like `.closest()` or `.next()`.